# The waiting time is exceeded when i'm updating the tables with a csv

Tags: php, sql, csv

I have this script, it works, i can make an update for the quantities . The only problem i have is the fact that the csv is too big... 
I tried to set the memory limit but when i'm loading the page the server says "The waiting time is exceeded. The server at www.auto-univers.fr takes too long to respond. "

What can i do ?

is that it is possible to update the line from 1 to 1000 for example? I do like his two update in 2 different pages, line 1 to 1000 and 1000 to the end line.

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');


function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}

function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
            WHERE
                entity_type_id = ?
                AND attribute_code = ?";
    $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}

function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}

function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function _getIdFromSku($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
}

function _updateStocks($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newQty         = $data[1];
    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

    $sql            = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " csi,
                       " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_status') . " css
                       SET
                       csi.qty = ?,
                       csi.is_in_stock = ?,
                       css.qty = ?,
                       css.stock_status = ?
                       WHERE
                       csi.product_id = ?
                       AND csi.product_id = css.product_id";
    $isInStock      = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $stockStatus    = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $connection->query($sql, array($newQty, $isInStock, $newQty, $stockStatus, $productId));
}

$csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->setDelimiter(';');
$data               = $csv->getData('supply.csv'); //path to csv
array_shift($data);

$message = '';
$count   = 1;
foreach($data as $_data){
    if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0])){
        try{
            _updateStocks($_data);
            $message .= $count . '> Success:: Quantité (' . $_data[1] . ') de la référence (' . $_data[0] . ') a été mis à jour. <br />';

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $message .=  $count .'> Erreur:: Lors de l\'update  de la quantité (' . $_data[1] . ') de la référence (' . $_data[0] . ') => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        }
    }else{
        $message .=  $count .'> Erreur:: Produit avec la référence (' . $_data[0] . ') n\'existe pas.<br />';
    }
    $count++;
}
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm skeptical this script would exceed max execution time, but to answer your question, you could always keep track of how many lines have been processed and then stop execution after 10000. You could also use an offset and limit passed in from the $_GET parameters to make it more controllable and dynamic.

Comment: It's a good idea or i should maybe split the csv in two parts before ? How can i do it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can either split the csv or use array_slice method to split the results from csv.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: It depends on the total number of records in ur csv. For instance you can split the files 10000/row.